# how can change numpy array to single value?

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I loaded mat file and I get followed dictionary.

| key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | [[Numpy array],[Numpy array],...] |
| B | [[Numpy array],[Numpy array],...] |
| ... | ... |

So, I changed this dictionary to Dataframe using `X = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(Y)`

| Index | A | B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [array(0.)] | [array(10.)] | ... |
| 1 | [array(1.)] | [array(11.)] | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

But, I expect to followed dataframe.

| Index | A | B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0. | 10. | ... |
| 1 | 1. | 11. | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

(The single value type whether int or float is not important to me.)

**How can change numpy array to single value?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the elements in your dataframe are lists with a single element. To get rid of that, you can simply use the pandas method `explode`. So in your case, `X = X.explode(['A','B'])` for all your columns. If you still struggle having numpy arrays instead of floats, `X = X.astype(float)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I can solve this problem thanks to your advice. Using `X=X.apply(pd.Series.explode)`, all columns in X Dataframe change a single value. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! It would be nice if you could accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I use this stackoverflow for the first time, so I'm not used to it. :( I think I accepted your answer now! If not, please leave a comment again!