# How to convert list elements in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
imp=[]
feature1 = []
issued = []
used = []
with open("lmutil_lmstat.txt", "r") as input:
    f=open("lmutil_lmstat.txt","r")
    found = False
    for x in f.readlines():
        if ("Users" in x):
            found = True
            feature1.append(x.split(" ")[2][:-1])
            issued.append(x.split(" ")[6][:])
            used.append(x.split(" ")[12][:])
            #print(x)
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'Feature_Name': [feature1], 'Licesence_Issued': [issued], 'Licesence_Used':[used]})    
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
with open('license_summery1.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(data_frame)
```

This is my code I am taking specific data from file and store it in the list. while creating data frame I am getting the output (1, 3) but I want to create a table with output (57,3)
Please check the above code and give suggestions. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually just answered the same question here: [how can change numpy array to single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73797806/9578926)

You can use `explode` on your dataFrame. If you have multiple values in every element, it will expand your rows with single elements.

```
data_frame = data_frame.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```